# how use setInterval in pug?

Tags: javascript, node.js, pug

i want make a clock using pug and nodejs

`node`

```
let clock
function getClock() {
  ~
  clock = `${hours}:${minutes}:${seconds}`;
}

app.get("/main", (req, res) => {
    ~
    res.render("mainP.pug", { lists: rows, getClock: getClock(), clock:clock });
  });
});
```

`pug`

```
    script 
        - setInterval(getClock(), 1000);
    body 
        .header 
            .clock#clock= clock
```

error is getClock is not function how can i solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't serialise a function defined in your Node.js program and send it to the browser.

Instead, generate a `<script>` element in the HTML document with either (a) the source code of the function as a text node inside it or (b) a `src` attribute pointing to a URL from which the script can be downloaded.

You'll also need to move the logic that generates the `hours`, `minutes` and `seconds` values into that script or use additional page loads / Ajax / WebSockets to get values for them from the server.